# how can I list all uncompresed files in btrfs?

Tags: btrfs

I can see there are files not compressed. I want to know which files they are, so I can get a feeling of what is compressed what is not.

```
 sudo compsize ./
Processed 1541 files, 13963 regular extents (13963 refs), 357 inline.
Type       Perc     Disk Usage   Uncompressed Referenced  
TOTAL       32%      598M         1.7G         1.7G       
none       100%      168M         168M         168M       
zstd        26%      430M         1.6G         1.6G
```

is there way to list all files fail into none type?